# I want to create a mapping table in which i want to store old_id and it's respective new_id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables profession and level.I am adding new id for same level and same profession.So the table have both newid and oldid in it.But now i want to create a mapping table which will contain this mapping.

I have this:

**Profession**

```
id  name    country
1   doctor  india
2   nurse   india
11  doctor  US
22  nurse   US
```

I want :

**ProfessionMapping table**

```
Oldid   Newid
1       11
2       22
```

And this is the same case for level table too.

Comment: How do you identify which is old and which is new ID. And how do you link the old with new ?

Comment: Hi Squirrel , I am inserting data in table profession using 1 SP,which will take input parameter as countryid.So i am passing india as @sourceicountryid and inserting whaterver records i have against india ,for US.(here US is @newcountryid)......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the oldid always comes from India and the newid always comes from the US, you can self join the `profession` table according to the name and differentiated by the country:

```
SELECT o.id AS oldid, n.id AS newid
INTO   ProffesionMapping
FROM   Proffesion o
JOIN   Proffesion n ON o.name = n.name AND o.country = 'india' and n.country = 'US'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
SELECT OLD.ID AS OLD_ID
     , NEW.ID AS NEW_ID
     INTO TBL_MAP
FROM     
(
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE ID <= 2
) OLD
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE ID > 2
) NEW
ON OLD.NAME = NEW.NAME
```

Comment: this is temporary solution.It wont work for 'n' number of records.

Comment: Sure, it was only an example of partition. The core is in the suqueries.